# virtualenv not installing correctly in Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I am new with Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to install virtualenv for python using " http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/" link
at step 8:

```
enter code hevasu@vasu-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
[sudo] password for vasu: 
The directory '/home/vasu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/vasu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr>=1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarningre
```

Why do I have this permission issue, as I am the only user.

Due to this I have to repeat whole step 8 to enter in virtualenv instead of workon cv" so that I could user cv2.

Comment: Do a `pip install` rather than a `sudo pip install`.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a very good reason to want the very latest version of virtualenv you should not `pip install` it in the first place. There's native ubuntu packages for those which insulate you from these kind of (perceived) issues. Just do `sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper python-virtualenv` and you're done.

You can always search your available package with `apt-cache search SOME_PACKAGE_NAME`

As for your actual question: You may be the only human to use your computer, but the linux OS always has more than one user entity. Using `sudo` you change as what user the following command runs. For your pip use case that's not important who owns the cache dir. Also, the pip install actually says everything you need is already present on your machine.